# htaccess doesn't load new js/css from another vhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, so here it is!
I have two virtual hosts, named main.aaa.com and static.aaa.com.

I have a htaccess rule in main.aaa.com that for each path that contains js|css|img|ico will load them from static.aaa.com.

This is the htaccess for main.aaa.com:

```
Options +Indexes
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks


# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

#
#  Rules
#

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule !\.(css|js|ico|img)$ index.html [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+\.(css|js|img|ico))$ http://static.aaa.com/$1  [L]
```

What's going on is that everything works perfectly, absolutely perfect, but...
if I create a new file in static/js folder and try to load it in main.aaa.com index file, it just gives a 200 OK, file not changed, and by looking into it it seems that htaccess doesn't even bother to look for the file in static vhost.

I have changed file permissions to 755, all of the files have the same permissions and the same owner, only that the new ones that I create are not loaded.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

[EDIT]: I tried also to rename a file that is now correctly loaded, because I thought I am missing something about file permissions. Stopped working. Renamed it back to previous name and it loads. So, I am thinking, is there a history of files or something that I can clear? I am at the point to break something, anything!
Using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and apache 2.4 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, I don't really understand why it works, I just hope it does not introduce any other problems when I push my files to my hosting.
So here it is, if anybody is as stupid as me :), I have changed and moved this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(css|js|img|ico))$ http://static.aaa.com/$1  [L]
```

above this line

```
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|ico|img)$ index.html [PT,L]
```

the final result being this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(css|js|img|ico))$ http://static.aaa.com/$1  [R,L]

RewriteRule !\.(css|js|ico|img)$ index.html [PT,L]
```

Good luck!

EDIT: maybe the answer is that redirects, with R flag, must be written first. Maybe.